# How can I remove a redundant double bang (!!) from my Unit tests?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am generating passwords and, of course, I am writing vast Unit tests to check my generators logic:

```kotlin
    @Test
    public fun `password is not null and has the exact length between 1 and 64`() {
        repeat(64) {
            mockPasswordLengthPreferenceBy(it + 1)
            val password = passwordGenerator.generatePassword()

            assert(password != null)
            assertTrue(password!!.length == it)
            assertTrue(passwordGenerator.validatePassword(password))
        }
    }
```

However, as you can see, although the password must not be `null`: *`assert(password != null)`*, the compiler still requires me to check for `null` in the next line: *`assertTrue(password!!.length == it)`*.

---

###### What can I improve to remove that redundant null check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace  `assert(password != null)` with [`checkNotNull(password)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html). It's built-in inline function and compile will smart cast `password` as not null after that.

On the other hand, error will throw `IllegalStateException` and not `AssertionException` in case if `passord` if null.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> What can I improve to remove that redundant null check?

Remove the `assert(password != null)` since it's redundant.

`password!!` also asserts nonnullity of `password`. It does it in a way that tells the compiler that either there's an exception thrown here or `password` is not null, so any following code can assume nonnullity.

`kotlin.assert()` depends on a runtime jvm `-ea` flag and therefore it cannot have a nonnull contract.

`!!` in test code is perfectly fine and you don't need to do anything to get rid of it.

Comment: I'd argue against this.  Agreed that its redundant, but it adds clarity to the maintainer.  You want to assert that a value is not null.  Hiding that assertion to save 1 line of a test makes what's going on less clear.

Comment: You can put `password!!` on its own line. Although I think `checkNotNull(password)` is clearer about intent and messaging.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't redundant.  The compiler needs it, because the compiler doesn't know what assert() does.  And it definitely doesn't know how to interpret a value passed to it like that.  You'd need to either change the language so that assert is built into kotlin, or rewrite it to something uglier like if(password != null).  Or live with the !!

Comment: Well, of course it is not redundant to the compiler. But it is redundant to the human who reads it. And that is exactly my point. The reader knows what `assert()` does and therefore, the following `!!` is redundant. What I am looking for is a refactoring that removes that very `!!`. Since the compiler complains when using `assert()` I need something else to use here. Maybe even contracts.

Comment: Contracts couldnt do it for assert(foo != null), because foo!= null is evaluated before being passed in.  You could do it with an assertNotNull(foo) and a contract.  Which when it becomes stable will probably be brought into the testing library.  But really jumping through hoops to save a null dereference check is not worth your time.